# Arch Linux freezes during boot and conflicting video drivers

Tags: linux, boot, graphics-card, arch-linux

I recently managed to install Arch Linux onto my Macbook (2,1). It's working fine for me, except for a more or less dramatic problem during the boot process.

In almost 2 out of 3 cases i get the following error message while the system seems to freeze:

```
fb: conflicting fb hw usage inteldrmfb vs EFI VGA - removing generic driver
```

Sometimes it boots fine though.

Any idea how to solve this? Thank you in advance.

=================================================================================

UPDATE: As i have tried to disable gfx mode as decribed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169912/fb-conflicting-fb-hw-usage-inteldrmfb-vs-efi-vga-removing-generic-driver) i could see the actual error message popping up:

```
...intel_display_capture_error_state+0x6b/0x2a...
```

`...`

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
```

Mysteriously though my laptop seems to boot without any problem most of the time and the error reappears not as often as in the beginning.

Comment: This is *not* an error message. It's logged as `kern.info` and is just to inform you that the `inteldrmfb` driver is taking over graphics control from the previously-loaded generic one. You'll find it in `dmesg` even after normal boots.

Comment: This explains why i see the message upon normal boots. But in case my laptop won't boot, this is the last output i see. Setting the flag "nomodeset" is a workaround i found and the system boots every time normally, but obviously X won't start with it.

Comment: I assume you've read [the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBook)? Also, 2.1 is a very old version of MacBook, so it may be hard to find help with it.

Comment: There is actually a full Wiki page dedicated to the MacBook which also includes a section for mine which i found to be very useful. I am quite happy with the setup so far.